Nav Controller on Android Studio Kotlin
Sorry for the question but im really a newbie about kotlin and android studio.
I have a MainActivity that is my "Home"  where i have 5 fragments like for Login,register in my fragment container view ecc...
Now i want to implement a NavBar that let me return to home (my main activity) and navigate to other fragments should i use another fragmentcontainerView?
thats my xml for main activity, i already tried to change my fragment container view and add navgraphs ecc but it seems to not working any suggestion?
``<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A5BAC8"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fra"
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="723dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />`


`

You have missed two attributes.

defaultNavHost
navGraph

In my example nav_graph_for_host.xml is my navigation graph. I am hoping you have already configured your navgiation graph xml.
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fcvNavHost"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_for_host" />

